Micorsoft Graph - Search query not getting results
I have a Sharepoint site setup and made a whole structure with folders to divide our attachments in a neat order. But when i need to look up certain folders I needed to have a way of finding the correct folders based on an ID within my system.
So what I did was I've added [] to the folder names and use that to look it up via the search/query endpoint in MS Graph. But for some reason this seems to be highly inconsistent.
So here's the folder Reports that has a few sub folders with unique identifiers in their folder name.

When I navigate to this Reports folder in MS Graph and ask it to list it's children, I get all of them back in the result. So they do exists according to MS Graph.
When I try to find the folder with [1408] in the name I don't get any results back via the following endpoint https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
"requests": [
    {
        "entityTypes": [
            "driveItem"
        ],
        "query": {
            "queryString": "filename:\"[1408]\" AND Path: https://<sharepointsite>/Shared%20Documents/Sharepoint/bemetdocrepo/Reports/"
        }
    }
]}

But if I look for the folder with [590] in the name, I do get a result back. The [1337] also gives a result but the others for some reason don't. What am I doing wrong here?
Edit; And just after i post this question, i try it again in Graph Explorer and for some reason it does return a result? Microsoft seems to be trolling me...
Edit 18-7-2024:
And again i'm in this situation; I'm trying to search for a file in a directory using the relative path. But it's not finding any file. But when I list the children of the folder I can see they are there.
Using this in the request:
{
"requests": [
    {
        "entityTypes": [
            "driveItem"
        ],
        "query": {
            "queryString": "\"PCF\"",
            "queryTemplate": "({searchTerms}) Path:\"https://<site>/Shared%20Documents/Sharepoint/folder/Calculations/2023-07/00888 [633]\""
        }
    }
]

}

Please use following query in the request body.
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "driveItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "[1408] path:\"https://<sharepointsite>/Shared Documents/Sharepoint/bemetdocrepo/Reports\""
            }
        }
    ]
}

Here is a graph search example:


It works yeah but won't work for me since I want to exclude files from the query. I only want to search for folders. That's why my search query is like that, but i removed the AND isDocument=false part to see if that would work.
